# FT230X no handshaking signals

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, circuit-design, uart, ft232

I'm new to digital circuits so I apologize if this is a stupid question.

I'm building a small circuit where a mcu is connected to a FT230X ic to enable the internal uart to communicate with a computer via a USB port. The FT230X ic has the flow control signals CTS and RTS but the uart on my MCU side does not. Can I leave these pins unconnected? The datasheet(https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/163/DS_FT230X-5395.pdf) does not mention anything on how to handle pins when they are not used. In addition I don't want to use the CBUS. Can I also not connect them to anything?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to connect the cbus pins to anything.  FTDI has an [application note](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/AppNotes/AN_216_Using_the_FT230X_to_design_a_GPS_Dongle.pdf) on connecting a GPS using the FT230X which connects CTS directly to RTS.  I have left them floating without issue in the past, but connecting CTS to RTS seems like a better idea.

Check the circuit on page 3 of the application note linked above.